# Sync all files mirrored with 2 Macs

Tags: osx

I started my "dual-Macs" lifestyle, currently I need to stick only with one Mac to get my work done because all my files are in that Mac.

I wanted to sync all files automatically from my primary Mac to secondary Mac.

Can anyone recommend me an application that supports this feature? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please improve your question by answering the questions at http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/844 especially in the *Synchronization/backup software* section? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same setup: two Macs that I want synched. 
I can totally recommend the **free [BitTorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync)**. It allows you to select (multiple) folders to be synched. For each folder you get a secret key. When you enter that key on the other Computer the folders will synch.

**It's a bit like Dropbox but with some major advantages:**

- The file transfers are encrypted (with that secret key)
- There is no server. Synching happens when both Computers are online
- You can setup the sync to only happen locally over your LAN (not over the internet)
- It is amazingly fast. Small files are synched 'instantly'
- You can sync multiple folders
- Folder size is only limited by your hard disk capacity

For example I have have setup BitTorrent Sync to sync my Desktop, Documents and Pictures folders.

Also, BitTorrent Sync is not limited to 2 Macs. You can sync between several devices. There's even an iPhone App.

**Possible drawbacks exists, though:**

- BitTorrent Sync is still in Beta
- There is no server, so your Computers must both be online to sync
- There is no history like in Dropbox. When you delete a file it is gone on both devices. (Unless you have TimeMachine)

Comment: **When you delete a file in BitTorrent Sync it's not really gone** ... it keeps a 30 day history of deleted or modified files in the hidden archive folder in the root directory of the syncing folder (.sync/Archive ). So if you delete or change a file on one computer, the OTHER computer will archive the file into the archive folder.